# Error "global name 'PROTOCOL_TLS' is not defined" when importing urllib2

Tags: python, html

```
import clr
import sys
import json
import os
import random
import ctypes
import codecs
import urllib2
```

Those are my imports, and simply adding the import urllib2 I get the error:

"global name 'PROTOCOL_TLS' is not defined"

Removing the import fixes it. I've followed some steps i've found online, such as updating python's OpenSSL with no luck.

My goal is to have a script that can read a website with a large amount of data, then grab a certain code before a few specific streams, then write that code to a text file. Naturally it stops working before I can even read the site. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Post the entire error message so we can see some detail.  (Do you have your own `urllib2.py` module?)

Comment: `PROTOCOL_TLS` is a member of the `ssl` module; try importing that first.

Comment: Have you fixxed? i got this issue too

Comment: @GianmarcoFerruzzi I was working within a twitch chatbot that apparently doesn't allow imports of any kind. Very annoying, but at least I know why it doesnt work.